# I need to do this with ajax

Tags: ajax

```
<style>
    #number{height: 50px; color: #000; }
    </style>


Progress: <div id="number"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;
    d = 1;
function increment(d) {
    if(i<100){
        i+=d;
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i + '&#037;';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = 'done' ;
    }

}

setInterval('increment(d)', 1000);

</script>

<button type="button" id="button" onclick="d++">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</button>
```

i'm currently working on a web app with visual studio on asp.net mvc 4. i need to make a partial view that shows a counter that goes from 1 to 100. i added a button that increases by 1 the counter value on every click and another one for refreshing the page. how can i do this using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX *(Asynchronous Javascript and XML)* is for making web requests without visible page refreshes. That is not what you should be using this for. You can do this using `setTimeout`. I have provided a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svLw3/) for you to use.

**The important bits**

In Javascript, you can simulate asynchronous functionality using `setTimeout`. This function will allow the Javascript to continue executing, and after a given waiting period, will execute the code you provide.

```
function doSomething() { alert("hello"); }

setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
```

This will execute the `doSomething()` method.

***NOTE***: You pass the function as a *callback*. As in `doSomething` and not `doSomething()`.